# No se puede asignar la matriz de covarianza debido a la forma grande de la matriz de origen

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, manejo-de-memoria

Me gustaria obtener todos los medios, desviación de normas de un cartera de valores pero parece que mi cartera esta demasiado grande. En efecto con el siguiente codigo:

```
n_portfolios = 5
means, stds = np.column_stack([
    random_portfolio(df_new_copy[1:].values) 
    for _ in range(n_portfolios)
])
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-62c87a1a020c> in <module>
      2 means, stds = np.column_stack([
      3     random_portfolio(df_new_copy[1:].values)
----> 4     for _ in range(n_portfolios)
      5 ])

<ipython-input-151-62c87a1a020c> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2 means, stds = np.column_stack([
      3     random_portfolio(df_new_copy[1:].values)
----> 4     for _ in range(n_portfolios)
      5 ])

<ipython-input-141-3aebfc0c97df> in random_portfolio(returns)
     13     # This recursion reduces outliers to keep plots pretty
     14     if sigma > 2:
---> 15         return random_portfolio(returns)
     16     return mu, sigma

<ipython-input-141-3aebfc0c97df> in random_portfolio(returns)
     13     # This recursion reduces outliers to keep plots pretty
     14     if sigma > 2:
---> 15         return random_portfolio(returns)
     16     return mu, sigma

<ipython-input-141-3aebfc0c97df> in random_portfolio(returns)
     13     # This recursion reduces outliers to keep plots pretty
     14     if sigma > 2:
---> 15         return random_portfolio(returns)
     16     return mu, sigma

<ipython-input-141-3aebfc0c97df> in random_portfolio(returns)
     13     # This recursion reduces outliers to keep plots pretty
     14     if sigma > 2:
---> 15         return random_portfolio(returns)
     16     return mu, sigma

<ipython-input-141-3aebfc0c97df> in random_portfolio(returns)
      6     p = np.asmatrix(np.mean(returns, axis=1))
      7     w = np.asmatrix(rand_weights(returns.shape[0]))
----> 8     C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(returns))
      9 
     10     mu = w * p.T

<__array_function__ internals> in cov(*args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in cov(m, y, rowvar, bias, ddof, fweights, aweights)
   2452     else:
   2453         X_T = (X*w).T
-> 2454     c = dot(X, X_T.conj())
   2455     c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)
   2456     return c.squeeze()

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (7010, 7010) and data type float64
```

Aqui esta la caretera `df_new_copy[1:]`:

```
    ABI BB Equity   AD NA Equity    ADS GY Equity   AI FP Equity    AIR FP Equity   AMS SQ Equity   ASML NA Equity  BAS GY Equity   BAYN GY Equity  BBVA SQ Equity  BMW GY Equity   BN FP Equity    BNP FP Equity   CRH ID Equity   CS FP Equity    DAI GY Equity   DG FP Equity    DPW GY Equity   DTE GY Equity   EL FP Equity    ENEL IM Equity  ENGI FP Equity  ENI IM Equity   FP FP Equity    FRE GY Equity   GLE FP Equity   IBE SQ Equity   INGA NA Equity  ISP IM Equity   ITX SQ Equity   KER FP Equity   LIN GY Equity   MC FP Equity    MUV2 GY Equity  NOKIA FH Equity     OR FP Equity    ORA FP Equity   PHIA NA Equity  SAF FP Equity   SAN FP Equity   SAN SQ Equity   SAP GY Equity   SIE GY Equity   SU FP Equity    TEF SQ Equity   URW NA Equity   VIV FP Equity   VOW3 GY Equity  SX5E Index
Dates                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2019-02-27 09:10:00     0.000609    -0.016755   -0.000942   -0.000455   -0.001060   -0.001156   0.001110    -0.000595   -0.012139   -0.005338   -0.001087   -0.000298   -0.005329   -0.002539   0.000458    -0.003402   0.000970    0.000749    0.002073    0.004213    0.001128    0.000000    -0.000526   0.000300    0.000618    -0.004077   -0.001086   -0.003357   -0.001922   -0.004970   -0.000620   0.000981    -0.001154   -0.001450   -0.002239   -0.001803   0.002999    -0.000285   0.002952    0.000274    -0.006883   0.002868    -0.001028   0.001747    -0.001983   -0.002932   0.000825    -0.003332   3275.70
2019-02-27 09:20:00     -0.001676   -0.002226   -0.000943   -0.001366   -0.003185   -0.001447   0.000985    -0.000744   0.005137    0.002673    0.000408    -0.003431   0.003942    -0.000727   -0.002521   0.000379    0.000969    0.004484    -0.000691   0.001400    -0.000752   -0.002848   0.000131    0.000200    -0.003096   0.004852    -0.001631   -0.000177   0.001922    0.000766    0.000207    -0.003931   -0.000825   -0.000484   -0.001121   -0.003164   0.001496    -0.001426   0.000421    0.001370    0.000485    -0.003400   -0.001647   0.002034    -0.000794   -0.000280   -0.004546   0.003332    3273.88
2019-02-27 09:30:00     0.002437    0.004668    -0.000472   0.001366    0.001240    0.003181    0.001107    -0.001192   0.006275    -0.000191   0.002171    0.001195    0.001272    0.000363    0.002521    0.001891    0.001936    0.000000    -0.000691   0.003260    0.000000    -0.001427   -0.000921   0.000200    -0.001241   -0.000387   0.000272    0.000531    0.001199    -0.005376   -0.000207   -0.000657   -0.001156   0.000967    0.004105    0.004066    -0.001496   0.002423    0.000000    0.000547    0.000605    0.001064    0.004011    0.001450    0.000000    0.000699    0.005371    0.002260    3277.38
2019-02-27 09:40:00     -0.001522   -0.006006   0.000000    0.000000    0.001062    -0.001155   -0.002339   -0.003435   -0.002476   -0.003438   -0.001764   -0.001045   -0.005213   0.000000    -0.002063   -0.003595   -0.001451   -0.003361   -0.001038   0.002322    0.000376    -0.000714   -0.000658   -0.000901   -0.001657   -0.006802   0.000816    -0.005678   -0.002881   0.000385    0.000000    0.000985    0.000000    -0.001935   -0.002237   0.001352    0.000748    -0.002137   0.007965    -0.001095   -0.006314   -0.001064   -0.004217   -0.004648   -0.000795   -0.001959   -0.000824   -0.001594   3272.65
2019-02-27 09:50:00     -0.000610   -0.002234   0.000943    0.000910    -0.000354   -0.001736   -0.001357   -0.000748   0.006396    0.001147    0.000407    -0.001645   0.002320    -0.003640   -0.000688   -0.000569   -0.000242   0.000748    -0.000692   -0.001857   -0.001129   -0.002504   -0.001054   -0.001003   -0.001037   0.003698    -0.000272   0.000000    0.000240    0.000000    -0.002483   -0.000656   -0.000661   0.000484    0.000000    0.000000    -0.000748   -0.001285   0.001252    -0.000685   0.001096    -0.000319   -0.001444   -0.002916   -0.001061   0.000840    0.000412    0.000532    3271.90
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2019-09-06 15:20:00     0.000357    0.000920    0.001619    0.000000    0.000315    0.000000    -0.000695   -0.000813   -0.000748   -0.001332   -0.000636   0.000000    -0.000118   -0.001308   -0.000464   -0.001097   0.000000    0.000000    -0.000530   -0.000367   -0.001660   -0.000733   -0.000435   -0.000657   0.000335    0.002076    -0.000213   0.000547    -0.000484   0.001755    -0.001103   -0.001757   0.000264    0.000899    0.000110    0.000000    0.000000    0.000349    -0.000352   0.000617    -0.001975   0.000360    0.000650    -0.000779   -0.000909   -0.000420   0.000000    0.000132    3488.78
2019-09-06 15:30:00     0.000833    -0.001151   -0.001079   0.002010    -0.000315   -0.001174   -0.002554   -0.002444   -0.002699   -0.003005   -0.003027   0.002447    -0.001884   -0.000655   -0.001626   -0.000659   0.000000    -0.002467   -0.000663   -0.000367   -0.000151   0.001831    -0.002033   -0.001645   -0.001231   -0.001038   0.001066    -0.002960   -0.001211   -0.003161   -0.001656   -0.001466   -0.001587   -0.000899   -0.002760   0.001194    -0.000731   0.000000    0.001056    0.001850    -0.003962   -0.001980   -0.002818   -0.002079   -0.000758   0.002098    0.000395    -0.002509   3485.89
2019-09-06 15:40:00     0.002731    0.002070    0.001079    0.003208    0.002205    0.002640    0.002786    0.002119    0.001350    0.001448    0.001753    0.001710    0.001178    0.003597    0.001162    0.001536    0.002198    0.001974    0.001723    0.001100    0.001057    0.001097    0.000872    -0.000768   0.000671    0.001660    0.000639    0.002084    0.000969    -0.001408   0.001877    0.001466    0.002115    0.001348    -0.000774   0.001589    0.001461    0.001396    0.004564    0.001847    0.001558    0.003237    0.000976    0.002598    0.001061    0.000000    0.001184    0.001982    3491.84
2019-09-06 15:50:00     0.000474    0.000459    0.000359    0.001200    -0.000472   -0.000879   0.000695    -0.002608   -0.000900   -0.000891   -0.001594   -0.000244   0.000353    -0.000980   0.000696    -0.001976   -0.000499   -0.000493   0.000132    -0.001100   0.001056    0.000365    -0.000436   -0.000659   -0.000895   0.000415    0.001064    0.000219    0.000726    0.005970    -0.000993   0.000000    -0.000264   0.000000    0.001990    -0.000794   0.000730    -0.000233   -0.001753   -0.000984   -0.001700   -0.000359   -0.001628   -0.001558   -0.001517   0.000419    0.000000    -0.001453   3490.35
2019-09-06 16:00:00     0.000474    0.000000    0.001616    0.000000    -0.001103   0.000000    0.002545    -0.000980   0.000150    -0.001003   -0.006883   0.000000    -0.001296   -0.000327   -0.000696   -0.003742   0.000499    -0.000987   -0.000397   -0.000734   0.002108    0.000000    -0.000727   -0.001100   -0.001232   -0.000622   0.003184    -0.001096   -0.000969   0.000000    -0.000552   0.001464    0.001188    0.000449    -0.002322   0.000794    -0.000730   0.000233    -0.001053   0.001476    -0.001703   0.000000    -0.000434   -0.001300   -0.000455   -0.000419   -0.000394   -0.003708   3490.09
```

## Computando la matriz de covarianza yo mismo:

Utilicé el intento de Kangchenghou para construir el mío propio. Parece estar basado en Python 2.7, así que intenté actualizarlo.

```
def compute_mean_std(mat, chunk_size):
    row_count = shape(mat)[0]
    col_count = shape(mat)[1]
    mean = np.zeros(col_count)
    std = np.zeros(col_count)

    for i in range(0, col_count, chunk_size):
        sub_mat = mat[:, i : i + chunk_size]
        # num_samples x chunk_size
        sub_mat = sub_mat.read().val
        mean[i : i + chunk_size] = np.mean(sub_mat, axis=0)
        std[i : i + chunk_size] = np.std(sub_mat, axis=0)

    return mean, std

chunk_size = 1000
means, stds = np.column_stack([
    compute_mean_std(df_new_copy[1:].values, chunk_size)
    for _ in range(n_portfolios)
    ])
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-d91a98f2d22c> in <module>
      7 means, stds = np.column_stack([
      8     compute_mean_std(df_new_copy[1:].values, chunk_size)
----> 9     for _ in range(n_portfolios)
     10     ])

<ipython-input-41-d91a98f2d22c> in <listcomp>(.0)
      7 means, stds = np.column_stack([
      8     compute_mean_std(df_new_copy[1:].values, chunk_size)
----> 9     for _ in range(n_portfolios)
     10     ])

<ipython-input-20-e7c28abb9639> in compute_mean_std(mat, chunk_size)
      8         sub_mat = mat[:, i : i + chunk_size]
      9         # num_samples x chunk_size
---> 10         sub_mat = sub_mat.read().val
     11         mean[i : i + chunk_size] = np.mean(sub_mat, axis=0)
     12         std[i : i + chunk_size] = np.std(sub_mat, axis=0)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: El error que da es por no poder reservar memoria para unos 375 MB. Evidentemente, debes estar gastando memoria en otra parte, con lo que no es posible saber cuál es tu problema con la información que das.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Claro, ¿qué información puedo añadir?